# How do you find inflection points from a graph?

Tags: calculus

Before you get upset that it's already answered somewhere on the internet, I thought so as well. In fact, I immediately googled it and went to Khan Academy, only to get 10x more confused. In the KA lesson, the inflection pts are the critical pts, but in their lesson quiz, it's the pt where the concavity changes. So which one is it?

[KA Lesson Quiz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0n6r.png)

[KA Lesson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAnli.png)

Comment: It's a point $c$ where the concavity changes, in the sense that $f''(c)=0$ *and* from left to right as one passes $c$ the sign of $f''(x)$ goes from (strictly) negative to (strictly) positive, or vice-versa.

Comment: hello is my answer helpful or confusing?

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind the picture in the one you called "KA Lesson" [second one you refer to] is already the derivative of the original function. So where that graph has a local min or max, the concavity of original function changes.

Comment: Yes, my bad! +1

Answer (score 1):

Because the graph in the Lesson is of the derivative, the leftmost inflection point is the leftmost point of where the slope of that graph is 0. Note that the derivative is positive to the left and right of the inflection point. This means the graph still has a positive slope. However it has changed from getting steeper to getting less steep, at this inflection point. You can imagine that the graph changes from "curving upward" to "curving downward."

For the quiz, the answers are A and C. For A, the second derivative changes from negative to positive, and for C, from positive to negative. The second derivative is a rate of change of the first derivative. So for A, the slope changes from getting more negative/less positive to getting more positive/getting less negative. For C, it is the opposite.

Comment: You are amazing thank you

Comment: good work @coffeemath

Comment: oh sorry, thought you were the answer creator

Comment: good work stacker

Answer (score 1):

Inflection points are places where the concavity changes. Inflection points only occur at critical points, but not all critical points are inflection points. For example, all cookies are desserts, but not all desserts are cookies. So, first you need to find the critical points of $f(x)$ where the concavity COULD change. $f(x)$ is concave-down if $f''(x)<0$ and concave up when $f''(x)>0$, so the concavity changes when you cross from positive to negative, which MIGHT happen when $f''(x)=0$, or at an area in the graph where $f''(x)$ is undefined. After you find these critical points, you need to make sure the concavity actually does change by testing points close to the left and points close to the right of the critical point to make sure the sign changes. Then, that's when you find the inflection points.

Let's try an example $f(x) = x^4$. We get $f'(x) = 4x^3$, so $f''(x)=12x^2$. So, it looks like $f''(x)$ $=0$ when $x=0$, and $f''(x)$ is defined everywhere, so we don't look for undefined regions. Now, we need to make sure this critical point actually is an inflection point. So, we test near the critical point on the left $f''(-1) = 12(-1)^2=12$. This is positive, so graph concave up left of $x=0$. Now we test on the right $f''(1)=12(1)^2=12$. This is positive, so the graph is concave up on the right of $x=0$ as well. Since the graph is concave up to the left and right of $x=0$, the concavity doesn't change at $x=0$, thus $x=0$ is not an inflection point. So, there are no inflection points for $x^4$.

Let's try $f(x) = x^3$. We get $f''(x) =6x$. So, it looks like $f''(x)$ $=0$ when $x=0$, and $f''(x)$ is defined everywhere, so we don't look for undefined regions. Now, we need to make sure this critical point actually is an inflection point. So, we test near the critical point on the left $f''(-1) = 6(-1)=-6$. This is negative, so graph concave down left of $x=0$. Now we test on the right $f''(1)=6(1)=6$. This is positive, so the graph is concave up on the right of $x=0$ as well. Since the graph is concave down to the left and concave up to the right of $x=0$, the concavity changes at $x=0$, thus $x=0$ is an inflection point. So, there is an inflection point for $x^3$.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I really appreciate this.

Comment: +1 for the long text.

Comment: did you not think it was helpful? @Stacker

Comment: nah it's gooddd besides you shouldn't care what i think